# Getting the count of elements in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get the count of elements that after the 3rd comma and `not 0` in XSLT. This means I want count of `<td>` between `<td>MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary</td>` and `<td>MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary</td>`

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC, 2, 2, 4, 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HGT, 1, 2, 0, 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC, 2, 2, 3, 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VSD, , 4, 0, 9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>KJD, 0, 9, 0, 11</td>
  </tr>
</tablr>
```

Output should be:

```
<root>
  <num>1</num>
</root>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template name="NZX_Overview">
    <xsl:if test="table/tr/td[preceding::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary')]][following::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary')]]">
        <xsl:variable name="fields" select="count(table/tr/td[preceding::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary')]][following::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary')]][tokenize(text(), ',')[4] != ' 0'])" />
        <root><num>xsl:value-of select="$fields"/></num></root>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The output i am getting:

```
<root>
  <num>3</num>
</root>
```

I am getting output is not correct. the correct output value is `1`.

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Can you post minimal but complete and well-formed samples that demonstrate the issue? Do you have more than one `table`? I have tried to morph your sample into a minimal one, correcting the input to be well-formed, but at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEv9 the output is `<root><num>1</num></root>`.

Comment: *"elements that after the 3rd comma and `not 0`"* does not make sense. Please re-phrase.

Comment: @Tomalak `<td>HGT, 1, 2, 0, 4</td>` here 4th element is `0`. so we cant count it. `<td>ABC, 2, 2, 3, 10</td>`. here 4th element is `3`. It should be counted.

Comment: There are 2 items where the 4th element is not 0 in your example. Why is the correct result 1?

Comment: @Tomalak I want `<td>` between `<td>MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary</td>` and `<td>MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary</td>`

Comment: ...and now that it's clear what your requirements are, please put them into your question and remove the completely unclear first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(table/tr/td[preceding::td[starts-with(., 'MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary')] and following::td[starts-with(., 'MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary')] and tokenize(., ', ')[4] != '0'])" />
```

---

Not sure why you need the `starts-with` part.